# Truecrypt: can't mount, header corrupt

Tags: mount, truecrypt

I have an external usb-drive (NTFS) with 1TB of files, encrypted with Truecrypt. It worked fine for years, but as of today, i can no longer mount the disk. There was a message, saying the header is corrupted and it will now restore the header in the volume. The volume then showed up, but there was no access.
I have a backup file of the header, but when i try to restore it via "Tools" in Truecrypt, i get an error message,

> The file cannot be accessed, because it is used by another process.

No Antivirus- or Disk-Software running in the background.

When it was still working, Windows always showed an inaccessible disk and after mounting the usb-drive, the volume with the actual files appeared, but now there is only a normal, empty hard drive in Explorer. I recently reinstalled Windows, but it was still working fine after that. Is there still something i could do, to recover the volume?

Edit: tried mounting again with mount option "use backup header", volume shows up under "My Computer", but nothing visible in Disk Management. Analysis with TestDisk says

> Invalid NTFS or exFAT boot

and

> Invalid FAT boot sector

so far.

System: 
Windows 7, 64 bit,
Intel Xeon E3 1231V3,
Gigabyte H97M-HD3

Answer (score 0):

You may use
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
to find which process is holding access to the file.

To search, click the binocular icon and enter the file or disk reference.

You could also try this update while booting into Safe Mode.